# connection not working on using sockets library

Tags: apache, sockets, socket.io

I have a code which does not seems to be working when i try to work with sockets.io on apache 2.4 version, my console message is like this:

```
 Socket {
     connected: false,
     recovered: false,
     receiveBuffer: Array(0),
     sendBuffer: Array(0),
     _queue: Array(0),
     …
 }
 acks
     : {}
 connected
     :
     false
 flags
     : {}
 ids
     :
     0
 io
     :
     Manager {
         nsps: {
             …},
         subs: Array(1),
         opts: {
             …},
         setTimeoutFn: ƒ,
         clearTimeoutFn: ƒ,
         …
     }
 nsp
     :
     "/"
 receiveBuffer
     : []
 recovered
     :
     false
 sendBuffer
     : []
 subs
     :
     (4)[ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ]
 _callbacks
     : {
         $userExists: Array(1),
         $userSet: Array(1),
         $newmsg: Array(1)
     }
 _opts
     :
     hostname:
     "calendar.randhawaworld.com"
 path
     :
     "/socket.io"
 port
     :
     "443"
 secure
     :
     true[[Prototype]]:
     Object
 _queue
     : []
 _queueSeq
     :
     0
```

i made some mofifications in my virtual host file conf file, and restarted apache but it is still a problem:

```
<VirtualHost 172.16.10.100:80>
   ServerName calendar.randhawaworld.com
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/home

   RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} =Upgrade [NC]
 RewriteRule /socket.io/(.*) ws://localhost:8888/socket.io/$1 [P,L]

 ProxyPass /socket.io/ http://localhost:8888/socket.io/
 ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/  http://localhost:8888/socket.io/

   RewriteCon %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRul (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

but i am still unable to make it sockets.io connection work properly, any ideas and help would be appreciated

another question is, i see everywhere it uses localhost, is it default to use localhost becuase i managed to change the port to whatever i specified, will it still be hitting localhost and converting all traffic through my domain.

please guide i am stuck here

Also using latest sockets version